# Java library to create diagrams

Tags: java, graphics

Is there a good library to create and update diagrams in Java, for instance pie chart, bar diagramm, etc. or can I start to draw them myself with Java2D?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is a great choice.  I can recommend it highly.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to produce graphs (eg visualize numerical data, etc), like duffymo said, JFreeChart is possibly the best option.

On the other hand, if you want to create diagrams (ranging from flowcharts to UML) I would then recommend [jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) (open source), or even more powerful (but closed source): [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html)

Comment: Don't even mention yFiles, their pricing is outrageous. Like $20k per single developer.